# How to change the line style to arrow in genealogytree?

Tags: genealogytree

While going through the package genealogytree i was unable to find line style as an arrow. I didn't get know the idea to pass the keys in genealogytree option. Here is an M.W.E

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\tcbset{male/.style={colframe=red,sharp corners},female/.style={colframe=blue,rounded corners}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[template=signpost,male={red},female={blue}]{ parent{
        g[male]{first child}
        c[female]{second child}
        c[female]{third child}
        p[male]{father}
        p[female]{mother}
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that draws the edges as blue arrows on a yellow background:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\tcbset{male/.style={colframe=red,sharp corners},female/.style={colframe=blue,rounded corners}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[
    template=signpost,
    male={red},
    female={blue},
    edges={foreground={blue, thick,->},background={yellow, very thick}}
    ]{ parent{
        g[male]{first child}
        c[female]{second child}
        c[female]{third child}
        p[male]{father}
        p[female]{mother}
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Have a look at section 8.3 of the manual.